# Why does my <input> lose focus when I press a key

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and trying to create a simple addition program made with two components: one for the problem itself (2 random numbers, an input field, and a score) and the other with just a "Congrats!" message when the user type in 5 consecutive correct answers.

The issue: My input field loses focus after pressing a single key.

I did this before (following [CS50 beyond tutorial](https://youtu.be/9NQtG_IIh6M?t=4012) but this time, Im trying to re-create it using the useState hook. I believe my input field is being re-rendered after every key but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's what I have:

[image: Edit sleepy-cohen-r6h1x]

The expected behavior is for the input field to not to lose focus unless I click outside of it. Expected result should be the "Problem" then display "Congrats!" once the problems have been solved 5 times.

```
function App() {
  const [num1, setNum1] = useState(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10));
  const [num2, setNum2] = useState(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10));
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const Problem = () => {
    return (
      <div key={0}>
        {num1} + {num2}
        <br />
        <input
          key={0}
          value={answer}
          onChange={({target}) => setAnswer(target.value)}
          onKeyPress={checkScore}
        />
        <br />
        Score is: {score}
      </div>
    );
  };

  function checkScore(event) {
    ...
  }

  return <Problem />;

  // return score < 5 ? <Problem /> : <Congrats />
}
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow requires that code be available on Stack Overflow itself, not only on an external site like CodeSandbox. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to provide a small snippet of code that runs here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using vanilla JavaScript and having the same problem: I click into an input of type "text," then start to type.  Every time I press a character key on the keyboard, an onblur event (and an onfocusout event) is fired.  Using Opera 105.0.4970.34.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're recreating the `<Problem />` component in full on each render to `<App />` when the state changes, which removes the focus on the input. Instead of creating and using a  component, just return the input field:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dream-qxioq

```
function App() {
  const [num1, setNum1] = useState(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10));
  const [num2, setNum2] = useState(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10));
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  // Removed <Problem /> component

  function checkScore(event) {
     ...
  }

  return (
    <div key={0}>
      {num1} + {num2}
      <br />
      <input
        key={0}
        value={answer}
        onChange={({ target }) => setAnswer(target.value)}
        onKeyPress={checkScore}
      />
      <br />
      Score is: {score}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by returning `<Problem>` as a component. If you `return Problem();` then it works. Any idea why?

Comment: When using `Problem()`, it's invoked as just a function, meaning there is no Component for React to tear down and recreate. `<Problem />` is in the form of JSX, which tells react to use `React.createElement`. Short answer, piping it through React is different than just invoking it as a function.

Comment: but doesn't a `<div>` go through `React.createElement` too?

Comment: All JSX will get eventually get piped through, but the top-level component of `<Problem />` will recreate itself on every render, causing the focus loss.

Comment: Ah I get it now... even though the component is still created with a function called 'Problem' each time, it's effectively a brand new 'type' of Problem. If you move the Problem function out of App and pass in props then it works. Cheers!